# select rows and generate a new column based on condition SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have the following table in Oracle

```
Company   Rate   Period
1A        10     sep-16
1B        20     sep-15
1C        30     oct-16
1D        40     sep-16
1A        50     oct-16
2B        50     sep-15
1C        60     oct-14
```

I want to select some rows and add a value based on conditions. so the result will be similar to the following:

```
Company   Rate   Period    Currency
1A        50     oct-16    USD
1C        30     oct-16    AED
```

In the previous table, I am selecting only the companies 1A, 1C where Period ='oct-16'. and I need to add a column "currency" for each company where 1A=USD, 1C=AED

what I did is:

```
select company, PERIOD , Rate 
from TABLE_test 
where period='Oct-16' And Company='1A' 
    OR period='Oct-16' and Company='1C';
```

I managed to get the companies but failed at the currency column. is this possible using SQL command? please help.

Comment: Do you want to hard-code the currencies like that, or do you have a lookup table with "company" and "currency"? Hoping it's the latter, and in that case you need to join to the lookup table.

Comment: @mathguy I dont have currencies at other table. I just know them =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible using case condition:

```
    SELECT COMPANY,RATE,PERIOD,(CASE WHEN COMPANY='1A' THEN 'USD' 
                                     WHEN COMPANY='1C' THEN 'AED' END
                                    )CURRENCY
    FROM TABLE_TEST
    WHERE PERIOD='oct-16'
    AND COMPANY IN ('1A','1C')
```

Comment: this is GREAT!!. Thanx

Answer (score 3):

```
select company, PERIOD , Rate,
(CASE WHEN Company ='1A' THEN 'USD' WHEN Company ='1C' THEN 'AED'  END) "Currency"
from TABLE_test where...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Company, Rate, Period, 
  CASE WHEN Company='1A' 
    THEN 'USD' 
    WHEN Company='1C' 
    THEN 'AED' 
  END as Currency
FROM TABLE_test
WHERE Period = 'oct-16'
```

Comment: Thanks. but my issue is generating the Currency Column. can you help?

Comment: The parentheses around the CASE expression are NOT NEEDED (at least, not in Oracle).

Comment: @ShB, you can **upvote** my answer. :) glad to help ya